# Get txt lines into variables, divide by separators check and rewrite txt send command

Tags: linux, bash

I searched trough various examples and solutions but I can't get one working by now.

This is what I have: 
foo.txt:

```
var1:var2:var3:var4
var1:var2:var3:var4
var1:var2:var3:var4
```

etc.

I need a script which get to ***foo.txt*** open it and get **var3**.
if **var3** is less than 25, 
**outputs** 
`'echo command user password sendammount $var4 sendto $var2'`
and then **raise** *var3* by **1** in the txt, saves it and goes to next line doing the same, if **var3** is already 25 it just ***skips the line*** doing nothing and going to the next one, once last line fullfilled, **script closes** (It should run every hour but i've read it could be done with **`watch -n 5 foo.sh`** ).

```
var1=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d-)
var2=$(echo $STR | cut -f2 -d-)
```

What it does:

```
ABCDE-123456
var1:ABCDE
var2:123456
```

I don't get where do I edit the divider in the `var1=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d-)` expression?

Also can I set the variable just by deleting the echo?
I tried to lookup the editing part but I can't get my logic working till there..

Comment: You can learn an awful lot about Bash by reading the manpage.

Comment: The issue is that it's a 1time purpose only, as coding many other things I already lost alot of time trying to do it, and probably even after reading the manpage I won't be able to do the script myself again, at the end of the day I already lost time, and the task is not over.

Comment: Without meaning to come across as overly harsh, I do need to ask you why that is our problem.

Comment: You could open every one of the projects and say the same thing, for every question there is a solution wrote out there, simply the author didn't search enough or wasn't able to recognize the issue, without the meaning to be harsh, if I want a life lesson teaching I will make a post in the right section,by checking I can see im in the right one, youre probably not.

Comment: OK -- I'm done.  At my usual rate of $100 per hour, that'll be $25.  :D

Comment: So you say that I wrote this all 17 mins ago ~ and you did read and understand it all in less than 2 mins, and you done it in 15. hmm. Sketchy

Comment: I think the difference here, Demon Slayer, is that you do not have any code and are asking for a solution to be written for you.  You're apparently not interested in learning Bash, and you seem to be offloading your own time pressure onto this community.  That is _not_ how every other question on this site works.  And the ones that are similar to yours get downvoted and closed.  We are here to help, but you need to have made an effort so that we're not just here to do your work for you.

Comment: Yep.  Assumed that var3 was an integer, but other than that and the running it every so often, yes.

Comment: Im sorry paddy, I got you wrong.
I tried, but decided to not put my mistake of code as I don't understand it at all, will edit up with the code I'm up with, and if it's possible i'd like to understand it, but since I can't study it I have to find the logical connecting points between the code and the end of the other answers, and of this one.

Comment: OK -- works with decimals now, too! :D

Comment: Tried to edit up with what I got till now, I can't get half of what it's wrote in bash, so it would just be an insult for who is reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know how much I win.

```
#!/bin/bash
function usage(){
    echo "Usage: $0 <input_file>"
}

# Ensure we have an input file
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
elif [ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "-?" -o "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    usage
    exit 0
fi

input_file="$1"

# Get number of lines in file
nLines=$( wc -l "${input_file}" | cut -d' ' -f1 )

# Loop over each line in the file
for (( ii=1; ii<=nLines; ii++ ));do
    # Extract the line
    line=$( sed -n "${ii}p" "${input_file}" )

    # Parse by ':'
    var1=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f1 )
    var2=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f2 )
    var3=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f3 )
    var4=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f4 )

    # Parse var3 into whole part and decimal part
    whole=$( echo ${var3} | cut -d. -f1 )
    decimal=$( echo ${var3} | cut -d. -f2 )

    # If the whole part is less than 25...
    if [ ${whole} -lt 25 ]; then
        # Print desired command
        echo command user password sendammount $var4 sendto $var2
        # Increment whole part
        (( whole++ ))
        # Write back to original file based on whether there was a decimal part
        if [ -z "${decimal}" ]; then
            sed -i "${ii}s/^.*$/${var1}:${var2}:${whole}:${var4}/" "${input_file}"
        else
            sed -i "${ii}s/^.*$/${var1}:${var2}:${whole}.${decimal}:${var4}/" "${input_file}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'll leave it to you to check that the file is readable and writable.

Comment: It's arab for me, will try and tell you,
Ot: You won a cookie, but the most delicious on the planet, thank you.

Comment: Works like a charm, you awesome guy!

Comment: I have an issue.
If I run the script with this foo.txt
1B6TUUhfh77TpDMbCkALcjVkuMdmxLZJwB:1bkaXKb5SsW49ZfDMBo7gxxfXca5jcj97:5.0:0.0001 it does work.
if I run the script with another txt like:
1B6TUUhfh77TpDMbCkALcjVkuMdmxLZJwB:1bkaXKb5SsW49ZfDMBo7gxxfXca5jcj97:1.0:0.00032 
It does not work. not either an error, or anything.

Comment: I copied and pasted those lines EXACTLY.  They worked just fine.  However, there are a couple of odd, invisible characters embedded in your strings.  They show up in `vi` as "gxxfX<200c><200d>ca5j" in both lines. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm

Comment: i used a php string to append the string, do you know what might cause such an issue? thanks again.

Comment: Once using your script once or twice it does not work anymore, however if I create another txt file with the same string it and relaunch the script with the new .txt it works again, could you check your script again please? also var3 is an int, like 25, not 25.0

Comment: I don't know.  I just copied it, as it is above, to a brand new file.  (I'm actually on another computer now.)  I copied those messed up lines you you have, with their funky characters, and ran it until all the var3's were 25.  No problems at all.